# Confluence Group API

Tags: java, spring-mvc, confluence

We're creating small spring MVC 2.5 add-on to confluence. Currently we are investigating group management and read/write access to specific functions of our site.

Our architecture is a bit complex and I'm still learning, however on left side we have LDAP with groups and users, in mid there is our confluence that manages mentioned groups and users, finally on right side we have spring MVC.

Is there any Confluence API that can help me to manage groups ? During search I found [this](https://developer.atlassian.com/static/javadoc/embedded-crowd-api/latest/reference/com/atlassian/crowd/embedded/api/CrowdService.html), however I'm not sure is it proper or not - testing it is also hard because of deployment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some search and tests I found an interface that is sufficient for our needs [UserAccessor.getGroupsAsList()](https://docs.atlassian.com/confluence/latest/com/atlassian/confluence/user/UserAccessor.html#getGroupsAsList())) returns all groups in confluence and helps to manage them.